# Is it possible to customize openFeatureForm of PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, pyqgis, pyqt

I am a **beginner at PyQGIS**.

I am trying to create a plugin, which will be used to Add, Delete, and Edit the Feature.

It is more customized than which is provided by QGIS (2.2).

I am capturing the Points using RubberBand API and then Add the attributes for the feature using `openFeatureForm()`. The `openFeatureForm()` takes default values as NULL.

What I want is to customize this form. Like, populate some values with a Combobox (to allow a user to select the required values). Also for fields like the date, I want to put `DateTimePicker()` widget in the form.

So Is it possible to customize the form provided by `openFeatureForm()`?

Answer (score 2):

QGIS provides some UI widget types from the layer field config.

- "Value Map" providing a combo box
- "Date/Time" providing a date picker

To set these field widgets from Python, try this (pyqgis 2.18):

```
formConfig = layer.editFormConfig()
formConfig.setSuppress(False) # open edit form by default

i = layer.fields().indexFromName('combo-field')
formConfig.setNotNull(i, True) # input required
formConfig.setWidgetType(i, 'ValueMap')
formConfig.setWidgetConfig(i, {
    'label': 'fieldvalue',
    'label2': 'value2',
})
```

So for basic UI widgets you don't need to create a custom edit widget.
However if you need to validate field inputs based on other fields, you should create a custom edit widget.

---

To explore the available fields, use the QGIS UI:
In the *Fields* tab in the layer properties, you can set up certain input types for each field.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For customize feature form you should make form in QtDesigner and set ui to you layer.
https://qgis.org/api/2.2/classQgsVectorLayer.html#aed365f469a74156a577500bfdd0fdc80

example: 
my_vector_layer.setEditForm("C:/my_form.ui")

note: very important input widgets in form might have actually that name as in layer